# Python: how to create a list with names based on the content of a given folder?

Tags: python, list, csv, append, listdir

I need to create a list like this:
`myindex=['event 1','event 2','event 3', ..., 'event n']`, where `n` is the number of `csv` files I have in a given directory.

To implement this I wrote the following:

```
directoryPath=raw_input('Directory for csv files: ')
myindex=[] #'event 1','event 2','event 3','event 4','event 5','event 6'
for i,file in enumerate(os.listdir(directoryPath)):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        myindex.append('event '+str(i))
```

The directory I pass it has `n` `csv` files and `n` `jpg` files, but I only want to consider the former.

The result I get:
`myindex=['event 0','event 2', 'event 4', ..., 'event 2(n-1)']`.

The result I want:
`myindex=['event 1', 'event 2', 'event 3', 'event 4', ..., 'event n']`

**What should I amend in my block?** Thanks!

**EDIT**

What if I want the first element of `myindex` to be an empty `string`? So to have `myindex=['','event 1','event 2',...,'event n']`.

Comment: You need to create a counter variable and increase every time you read a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a counter instead of using enumerate since that increments for every loop

```
directoryPath=raw_input('Directory for csv files: ')
myindex=[''] #'event 1','event 2','event 3','event 4','event 5','event 6'

count = 0
for file in os.listdir(directoryPath):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        count += 1
        myindex.append('event '+str(count))
```

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani Just add it into the initialization of the list. If it is based on a condition then you could use `myindex.insert(0,'')`

Answer (score 3):

`enumerate` takes a second parameter that is the number to start with. Use `1`. Then use `glob` to count only csv files:

```
for i,v in enumerate(glob.glob('*.csv'),1):
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a genex to filter the filenames.

```
enumerate((x for os.listdir(directoryPath) if x.endswith(".csv")), start=1)
```

Or have the OS do it.

```
enumerate(glob.glob(os.path.join(directoryPath, "*.csv")), start=1)
```